# "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded" while downloading Google Document

Tags: java, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm developing application that have PHP front-end and java back-end and should authorize user from the front-end to access his Google Drive offline. Application should store Google access token and refresh token and use it later, without having user to explicitly allow it.
The problem is that java application can't download the file created from Google Drive and I'm always receiving the following error message  "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.". However, I don't have a problem to upload a file and to download those files uploaded from this client application.

The code on the PHP side looks like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the APIs Console
$client->setClientId('xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/google-test/index.php');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
print "AccessToken:\n$accessToken\n\n";
?>
```

And I'm receiving the following output

```
{"access_token":"ya29.AHES6ZRw6aUxSAlwunKlgJ1pWu0PD1tise_cu7IshJ8_Mg8",
"token_type":"Bearer", "expires_in":3600, 
"refresh_token":"1\/ZEU4mGWxEnrqogPVml3cHc5s9okqHplVZc3FhSF5sac",
"created":1379705627}
```

Java code to authenticate user and access his Google documents:

```
GoogleCredential.Builder credentialBuilder = new GoogleCredential.Builder();
credentialBuilder.setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory());
credentialBuilder.setTransport(new NetHttpTransport());
credentialBuilder.setClientSecrets("xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com","xxxxxx");
Credential credentials = credentialBuilder.build();
//credentials.setAccessToken("ya29.AHES6ZRw6aUxSAlwunKlgJ1pWu0PD1tise_cu7IshJ8_Mg8");
credentials.setRefreshToken("1/ZEU4mGWxEnrqogPVml3cHc5s9okqHplVZc3FhSF5sac");

Drive drive =  new Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,  JSON_FACTORY,   credentials)
.setApplicationName("API Project").build();
String query = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'";
try {
    Drive.Files.List request=drive.files().list();
    FileList tempFileList = request.setQ(query).setMaxResults(1000).execute();
    List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> files=tempFileList.getItems();
    for(com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file:files){
     GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl());
      HttpResponse response = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(url)
          .execute();
    }
```

I can access each of these files and output its titles, but once I try to download it, I receive the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires  signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Does anyone have idea what could be the problem with this? I tried several different approaches, and always stuck with the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that this is not related to the authentication nor google api limits, but to the way how I tried to download the content of the document.  It obviously can't be accessed as file.getDownloadUrl() as it is null for all documents where "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'".

Comment: You're right. You should use exportLinks for google docs. Having said that, I think the likely cause of that specific error message is that you didn't set the access token into the http Authorization header of the download request.

Comment: Thanks you for suggestion. exportLinks will do the job. Error message is not related to the access token. With or without access token I got this error message when I try to access some properties of File, such as getSelfLink(). This directed me to wrong direction, so I spent two days investigating if there is the problem in authentication.